# Why is the degree of the antipodal map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$ equal to $(-1)^{n+1}$ and not $(-1)^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

So the definition I have of degree is

$$
\operatorname{deg}(f,p)=\sum_{x\in f^{-1}(p)}\operatorname{sgn}df|_x
$$

Where $\operatorname{sgn}(T)=1$ if $T:V_1\rightarrow V_2$ preserves orientation of the vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$, and $\operatorname{sgn}(T)=-1$ if it does not.

So when I compute the degree of the antipodal map on $S_n$ in this way, I actually get $(-1)^n$ and can't figure out where the gap in my reasoning is.

So we have that if $f$ is the antipodal map, then

$$
\operatorname{deg}(f,p)=\operatorname{sgn}df|_{-p}
$$

And so for any $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\in T_{-p}S^n$ we have for any $g\in C^{\infty}(S^n)$ that

$$
df|_{-p}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})g=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g\circ f =\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g(-x_1,\dots,-x_n)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g
$$

and thus $df|_{-p}=-I_n$ which implies that

$$
\operatorname{deg}(f,p)=(-1)^n
$$

So where is the error? And is there a way to do this directly from the computation of $df|_{-p}$ instead of resorting to composition of reflections like most other answers? as we haven't proven that this definition of degree is multiplicative.

Comment: Try the $n=1$ case, where it is visibly clear that the antipodal map is homotopic to the identity.

Comment: You're using fixed coordinates coming from $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, which are positively oriented at $p$ but negatively oriented at $-p$.

Comment: The fact comes from that $S^{n}$ lies in $n+1$ dimensional space.